# Java Get URL Header Alone, Body Not Required

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine

Im using below code to get the cache-control value in header of given URL. I dont want to get the body of the URL. Below request takes 800ms to process. Is there any alteration can be done in below code? Im using Google App Engine for development. Please suggest. Thanks. I like not to add extra jar.

```
    URL obj;
    URLConnection conn = null;
    String noTransform = "";


    obj = new URL(url);
    conn = obj.openConnection();


    noTransform = conn.getHeaderField("cache-control");

    if (noTransform !=null && (noTransform.contains("no-transform") || noTransform.contains("private") )){
     news.setIsGoogleLiteURL("false");
     return news;

    }
    else {
         news.setIsGoogleLiteURL("false");
         return news;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a GET request, try making a HEAD request.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4

Comment: Thats is the question, how to make a Head alone request using java

Comment: You should be more specific the next time you ask a question.  Try using [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of URLConnection.  Then invoke [setRequestMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-)